# How should I pass a user-defined type to SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue?

Tags: parameters, types, sqlcommand, implicit-typing

I have a custom data type called `StudentID`, which has an implicit conversion to string.

When I pass a `StudentID` instance to `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` (as the value) and execute the command, I receive the following error:

```
No mapping exists from object type StudentID to a known managed provider native type.
```

Specifying a type for the parameter like `SqlDbType.NVarChar` doesn't help.  The only thing that works is to explicitly cast the `StudentID` value to a string, which defeats the purpose of having the implicit cast.

I guess the framework does not consider available conversions.  Is there anything I can do to the `StudentID` class to make the command handle it without requiring an explicit cast to a primitive type?

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) talks about how primitive types are handled, but not user-defined types.  The closest match would be object, which it says is passed as a Variant.

The exact point of failure is in the System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue method, with signature `private static MetaType GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, object value, bool inferLen)`.  Reflection reveals that it looks for primative types, and if the TypeCode is object, it looks for Sql* data types such as SqlBoolean, so it seems to be looking for very specific kinds of primitive or Sql* types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can't pass UDTs. Only primitive or Sql* types are allowed.

Comment: From what I'm reading it doesn't support Nullable<T> either, which is absurd, because passing data to and from a database seems like a core reason for introducing Nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use `SqlUserDefinedTypeAttribute` with your custom type. Take a look at the *current* implementation of `GetMetaTypeFromValue`.