# Map My Object For Use with ADO.NET

Tags: .net, ado.net

I am getting the exception "No mapping exists from object type MyType to a known managed provider native type." How do I provide a mapping?

I am sending the data to SQL Server through ADO.NET. I am basically going to transform MyType into an integer. I don't need it to come back as MyType. It's fine for it to come back as an int, though it would be nice for it to come back as MyType.

EDIT for those who insist on seeing code:

I have a type:

```
class MyType {
    int field1;
    int field2;
}
```

And I want to send a variable `paramValue` of type `MyType` to the database:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", paramValue);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

EDIT

Let's say I have a function:

```
class MyType {
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public int dbValue() {
        return field1 + field2;
    }
}
```

I want to use:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", paramValue);
```

instead of:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", paramValue.dbValue());
```

Because I don't want to have to put `.dbValue()` everywhere I send it to the database. This is just postponing the inevitable day that I forget to put `.dbValue()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've provided a code sample.

Comment: Your class has two `int` fields. Which do you want to use, both? However, why don't you add the fields as sql-parameter? `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1",paramValue.field1)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to use both. I've updated the question to include more details on why I don't want to do that.

Comment: It's not possible to add a custom type mapper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398325/creating-ado-net-mapping-for-custom-type But you could use [`Dapper.NET`](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) instead of `ADO.NET`. Here you can see some more details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET (basically it's just a micro ORM sitting directly on ADO.NET as a single class, but it's very useful)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for finding all that information.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Seeing as how it's a duplicate, should I delete this question or wait for others to close it?

Answer (score 0):

The database wouldn't know how to store `MyType`. You should provide it as 2 integers when you save it, and you should manually re-create `MyType` from the 2 integers when you read it.

Comment: I know how the database should store `MyType`. I want to know how to share that knowledge with the database, without sending it as 2 integers.

Comment: You can't share this knowledge with the database, which is why I've suggested that you just give it 2 integers that it does know how to store.